# How can I use the Google Classroom API to Add Coursework that links to my developer site?

Tags: google-api, google-classroom

Is there any documentation which describes how I can use the Google Classroom API to add coursework that links to my developer site?

At ck12.org, each Quiz has an [Assign To Class] button that adds that Quiz to Google Classroom. That Quiz then appears at Google Classroom on the Classwork tab, with the developer's logo. The dropdown menu includes an option to "Manage CK-12". When I click the entry, it launches the Quiz at the developer's website.

This API page does not explain how I can accomplish this:
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/create

Please point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried creating a courseWork already? can you show what you have tried? Please read [How-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)